# C# Sending one bit of information (= boolean) to another process without acknowledgement

Tags: c#, ipc

I currently have two processes and I would like to transfer a boolean from one process to another e.g. that the user pressed OK in a certain dialog. But I can't/don't want to wait for the other process to receive the information and I don't know whether or when the other process will receive the message.

Prerequisite:

- Both processes (applications) are written in C#
- Both processes know that the other process exists
- Both processes know a certain string/keyword that can be used to identify the other process
- Transfer is unidirectional, Process1 always sends data to Process2
- Process1 and Process2 are on the same Windows machine and only exist ones
- Process1 is always online, Process2 might be down

Options so far:

- [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile) (in memory)
- MemoryMappedFile (as file)
- [Named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream)
- [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf)
- good old file (actually not always that good)
- clipboard (yes, some people do this)

Some of the options are working but I think most of them are just overkill for this situation. The other problem is when to delete the piece of information (when to clean up the files or pipe).

Maybe there is some kind of cache that I can write to?

Do you have any ideas?

PS: If you post a technology please also provide a piece of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end we used [EventWaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle)

Process1

```
handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "KEYWORD");

if(secretHappened)
{
    handle.Set();
}
```

Process2

```
using(var handle = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("KEYWORD")) //this always happens after Process1 so we can assume that the handle exists
{
    if(handle.WaitOne(0))
    {
        //Do your secret stuff
    }
}
```

So far this works quiet well, the only problem is that the handle from Process1 must not get cleaned up by GC and it's hard the determine when to dispose the handle. We coupled the lifetime of the handle to the lifetime of Process2, once Process2 does not exist anymore we dispose the handle. This might take a while but that's what we did. Since we don't know whether the handle is used in Process2 we can't use that as an indicator to clean things up.